# Adding Column Headers in CSV with AWK in Terminal

Tags: linux, csv, unix, awk, terminal

Hello I'm trying to add column headers in my CSV file with awk in terminal.

Currently displays:

```
Michael, Michael@email.com, Seattle, Washington, detail1, detail2, detail3
```

Desired format:

```
Name, Email, City, State, more1, more2, more3etc
Michael, Michael@email.com, Seattle, Washington, detail1, detail2, detail3,
```

Have tried something like this, but I end up getting "Illegal Statement at Source line 2":

```
awk 'BEGIN {FS=",";OFS=","; print "Rating,Restaurant,Address,Landline,Mobile,Cuisine,Website,LatDD,LonDD"}
NR >1 {print ",",,,",",",", }' Restaurants.txt > Restaurants_newer.txt
```

Comment: Does this problem reduce to "Insert a line at the beginning of my file"?

Comment: And why is the first line in the desired format different from what you try to insert in your awk command?

Comment: The second print  has syntax errors: too many `,`.

Comment: for `BEGIN` use print "Rating", "Restaurant" and so on, with each header as one string and the different headers separated by a comma. Replace the second `NR >1 ... ,}` with `{print }` or just `1`.

Answer (score 6):

this will do

```
sed '1iName, Email, City, State, more1, more2, more3etc' file > newfile
```

can be done in place too

```
sed -i '1iName, Email, City, State, more1, more2, more3etc' file
```

or

```
{ echo 'Name, Email, City, State, more1, more2, more3etc'; cat file; } > newfile
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, but... I'm gettings this on terminal:

> command i expects \ followed by text

Comment: Not sure, and OSX.

Answer (score 3):

```
awk '
BEGIN { OFS=", "; print "Name", "Email", "City", "State", "more1", "more2", "more3etc" }
{ print $0, "" }
' file
```

Comment: Hmmm, this isn't working. My CSV file still shows up blank after I tried this.
Thanks though.

Comment: The script cannot do what you claim it is doing. When you say "My CSV file..." idk if you mean your input file or your output file but that script cannot empty your input file since it doesn't write to it and it cannot produce an empty output file since the BEGIN section will print a line no matter what. You're doing something wrong so edit your question to copy/paste the full command line you are running and the output it produces so we can see what you're doing to help you debug it.

Answer (score 1):

Using AWK :

```
awk 'BEGIN{print "Name, Email, City, State, more1, more2, more3 .."}1' Restaurants.txt
```

OR

Try this :

```
echo "Name, Email, City, State, more1, more2, more3 .." >> Restaurants_newer.txt
cat Restaurants.txt >> Restaurants_newer.txt
```

That is redirect the header line & the file output into a file.

OR

```
{ printf 'Name, Email, City, State, more1, more2, more3 ..'; cat Restaurants.txt; } > Restaurants_newer.txt
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, but... I'm gettings this on terminal:

> command i expects \ followed by text